# Is there a clan/bloodline that has all physical desciplines at in clan cost?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

I am currently looking towards building a very physical character, in Vampire the Requiem. I am wondering if there is any clan/ bloodline, that gains all physical disciplines (Celerity, Resilience, and Vigor) at a in clan cost?

Comment: That would be quite a boring clan...

Comment: Very true. I know that most bloodlines have four disciplines. I didn't know, if maybe there was one of the five clans that got such a thing, while retaining their normal clan power. Example: If a Daeva bloodline maybe got all three of those, while still having Majesty, or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No.

No such clan or bloodline exists.

It's easy to see why, from a game design point of view.  Such a clan would be superior in all physical activity - especially combat - while not possessing any original discipline or distinctive feel, since all it's abilities would be common across many clans.  (What would the defining 'feel' of such a clan be?  What kind of people would they Embrace, other than "physically fit"?)

Characters from this clan would have little to contribute in non-physical situations.  In a game about social interaction like Vampire, that would be the kiss of death to game design.  (Compare to, say, Gangrel - an example of a clan with a strongly physical nature, but a completely distinctive feel dripping with a personality that encourages several types of character design.)

It's perfectly OK to design a physical-only character, of course, but game designers wouldn't want to include a clan that *doesn't allow any other kind of character*.